# Logback : different different files for different log levels

Tags: java, logging, logback

I know that this type of question have been answered, but in my case i have tried every config and still doesn't work. I need a fresh view to my config (I am sure i'm missing something). both of the appenders log all levels

I want to log info >= for all packages to the console, and the errors only the erros to log file. In my case, both of them log info

Here is config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<!-- CONSOLE -->
<property name="LOG_PATTERN" value="%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- FILE FOR ERROR ONLY -->

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>/Users/dev/Desktop/JAC/logs/frontend/errors.log</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

    <fileNamePattern>/Users/dev/Desktop/JAC/logs/frontend/errors_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>
<encoder>
    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
    <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>


<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have 2 root level=INFO, is it normal ?

Comment: I have found somewhere in SO. maybe it's not.

Comment: it's surely not, place one root level in INFO, and the second one in ERROR

Comment: like that  <root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root> ?

Comment: It does not work there is no log in either console nor file.

Comment: look at n°3 http://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-xml-example/

Comment: i have tried that    <logger name="com.crossover" level="info"
            additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root> but it logs nothing to the file and it logs error to the console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be, it's not the more beautiful solution. But, in this case, log level INFO is logged in the console, and error is logged in a file. The debug level will be not printed. And INFO and ERROR are in only one exit.
And my application package is fr.myuser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="/home/myUser" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ERROR"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/error.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                        </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

    <!-- Send logs to console -->
    <logger name="fr.myuser" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```